# Adding rational expression: Why is $\frac{4}{a+1} + \frac{5}{a-3}$ = $\frac{9a-7}{a^2-2a-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

According to my textbook,

$$\frac{4}{a+1} + \frac{5}{a-3} = \frac{9a-7}{a^2-2a-3}$$

However, I get:

$$\frac{9}{a-3}$$

Here's my work:

The least common denominator is $(a+1)(a-3)$.

Multiply both expressions by the least common denominator:

$$\frac{4(a+1)(a-3)}{(a+1)(a+1)(a-3)} + \frac{5(a+1)(a-3)}{(a-3)(a+1)(a-3)}$$

Sum the numerators:

$$\frac{9(a+1)(a-3)}{(a-3)(a+1)(a-3)}$$

Cancel out common factors:

$$\frac{9}{a-3}$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at the textbooks solution of 
$\frac{9a-7}{a^2-2a-3}$?

Comment: Your sum of numerators is false.

Comment: You want to end up with a *common denominator* so you want to multiply each term with a different form of $1$: the common denominator as you note should be $(a+1)(a-3)$, so you want to multiply the first term by $1$ in the form $\frac{a-3}{a-3}$, but the second term by $1$ in the form $\frac{a+1}{a+1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of multiplying by the least common denominator (LCD), just multiply by whatever's needed to turn the denominators into the LCD. If you had to add $\frac14+\frac16$, for example, then instead of multiplying both fractions by $\frac{12}{12}$, you should multiply the first by $\frac33$ and the second by $\frac22$.

$$\frac14+\frac16=\frac{3}{\color{blue}{12}}+\frac{2}{\color{blue}{12}}=\frac5{\color{blue}{12}}$$

The point is to make the denominators the same so that you can add the fractions together. (Note that your calculation doesn't work because your denominators are different.)

Answer (score 3):

You get $$\frac{4(a+1)(a-3)}{(a+1)(a+1)(a-3)} + \frac{5(a+1)(a-3)}{(a-3)(a+1)(a-3)}$$

correctly. But you can't add the numerators because the denominators are different.

You say

> The least common denominator is $(a+1)(a−3)$.

which is correct, but you wrote down different denominators.

I want to point where is your mistake. There is a correct solution in other answer.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is

$$\frac{4(a-3)}{(a+1)(a-3)} + \frac{5(a+1)}{(a-3)(a+1)}$$

$$=\frac{4a-12+5a+5}{(a-3)(a+1)}$$

$$=\frac{9a-7}{(a-3)(a+1)}.$$

When you summed the numerators, the denominators were not equal; that was your mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $$\frac{4(a-3)}{(a+1)(a-3)}+\frac{5(a+1)}{(a+1)(a-3)}$$ for $$a\ne -1,3$$

Answer (score 1):

The least common denominator is $ (a + 1)(a - 3) $, so multiply the $ a - 3 $ by the numerator $ 4 $ on the first term and multiply the $ a - 1 $ by the numerator $ 5 $ on the second term, like this:

$$ \frac{4}{a+1} + \frac{5}{a-3} $$$$= \frac{4}{a+1}\cdot\frac{a-3}{a-3} + \frac{5}{a-3}\cdot\frac{a+1}{a+1} $$$$= \frac{4(a-3)}{(a+1)(a-3)} + \frac{5(a+1)}{(a-3)(a+1)} $$$$= \frac{4(a-3) + 5(a+1)}{(a+1)(a-3)}$$

Then simplify the numerator by distributing and combining like terms to obtain the desired result, and expand the denominator $ (a+1)(a-3) $.